# Problems with german umlauts in PHP

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am trying to get some data from my MySQL server, but german umlauts are converted to its unicode-specific code.

```php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"); 
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pwd', 'databasename');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM Table");
SQLtoJSON($result);


function SQLtoJSON($ab) {
    $tempArray = array();
    $myArray = array();
    while($row = $ab->fetch_object()) {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
```

The output:

```
[{"Name":"Frische-B\u00e4ckerei-Huber"}]
```

It should be:

```
[{"Name":"Frische-Bäckerei-Huber"}]
```

I also tried `$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'")`, but it didn't work. The server's charset is UTF-8.

**EDIT:** It's definitely a problem with json, *var_dump()* has the correct text.

Comment: Has your table the charset set to UTF-8?

Comment: Every json parsing library will understand it correctly, so I whould leave this as it is. That's just how unicode characters are represented in JS strings.

Comment: You have one `)` too many in `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8"));` change to `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` which is most likely the problem.

Comment: @gbestard yes the table's charset is UTF-8

Comment: use [`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE `](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

Comment: @Fred-ii- its only a typo, edited.

Comment: Had to be sure @Krystex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in MySQL. Actually, the fact that you get that unicode notation proves that the data is in fact interpreted as a UTF-8 character (and probably the *right* character as well ;)).

The problem is in encoding it to json. By default `json_encode` escapes those characters.

That is not wrong by the way. You are allowed to escape them, but JSON also allows UTF-8 characters to be unescaped. JSON isn't meant to be human readable per se. It's just a format to send data over the line. The receiving party should be able to unescape the unicode sequence and show it as a ü.

Anyway, since JSON can also contain unescaped characters, you don't need to escape them, and you can tell `json_encode` not to by passing a flag:

```
json_encode($myArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

See [`json_encode function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json constants`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

json_encode makes every ä to \u00e4. So i think the output is how it should be. just not the way you want ;)

Comment: Use htmlentities($item,NULL,'UTF-8') or utf8_encode($item)